# Add item to JList in IntelliJ-IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jlist

I cannot for the life of me get this to work and I have been trying for at least 15 hours total. Here is all my code. Please tell me what I am doing wrong that the items I want to add to my JList are not showing up when I run it but are being added to my listmodel.

These are the declarations for my jlist and defaultlistmodel.

```
private EventList issuesEventList = new BasicEventList();
public JList lstContacts;
```

Under this is all of my event listeners which do not have too much relevance and then my main function and my function to fill my JList:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ContactsDB contactsDB = new ContactsDB();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("VirtualRolodex");
    frame.setContentPane(new VirtualRolodex().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    contactsDB.createContactsTable();
    contactsDB.loadContactsList();
}

public void fillList(EventList<String> contactsList){
    issuesEventList.clear();
    issuesEventList.addAll(contactsList);
    DefaultEventListModel issuesListModel = new DefaultEventListModel(issuesEventList);

    JList lstContacts = new JList(issuesListModel);
    lstContacts.setModel(issuesListModel);
}
```

That is my class for my GUI Form and then I also have a database class that handles the writing and reading to and from the database.

```
 public void loadContactsList() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet results;

    Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT companyName,firstName,lastName FROM contacts;";
    contactList.clear();
    contactList.add("New Contact");
    try {
        results = statement.executeQuery(query);
        try {
            while(results.next())
            {
                String company = results.getString("companyName");
                String first = results.getString("firstName");
                String last = results.getString("lastName");
                contactList.add(company + ": " + last + ", " + first);
            }

            fillList(contactList);



        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println("Trouble accessing iterating through "+
                    "results in UsersDB.getAllUsers.");
            throw e;
        } finally {
            results.close();
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Trouble accessing getting results in "+
                "ContactsDB.loadContactsList()");
        throw e;
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

This is the code from that class that loads an eventlist with the contacts basic info that I want to be in the JList.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. All the information passes back to the main class but nothing is displaying in the JList. I'm also using Intellij which has the built in GUI builder so everything is already set up in the GUI.

Comment: This `JList lstContacts = new JList(issuesListModel);` would be my first concern, you are shadowing the `lstContacts` which seems to be declared as an instance field.  Next, `lstContacts` doesn't appear to be added to anything

Comment: What do you mean by added to anything? I have removed the JList part from JList lstContacts but im unsure exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: `lstContacts` is not added to any displayable component (based on our example code) so it will never be visible

Comment: It is displayable. It shows up and everything and I can add items to it myself in the gui builder but I can't add anything to it dynamically.

Comment: The it winds like you have a shadowing reference issue, but since the code is incomplete, all I can do is guess

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I give you a github link to everything I have will you be able to try to help me out. This project is due soon and I've gotten no help from anyone else. I would deeply deeply appreciate it. github.com/bmitrano825/FP3